# how to multiply two column names using codeigniter validation rule

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have three columns.The product of two columns get into third column name income_amount using codeigniter validation rule.the first column is crop_quantity and the second is per_rate

**controller**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('crop_quantity', 'Crop Quantity', 'required|numeric');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('per_rate', 'Per Rate', 'required|numeric|callback_get_product');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('income_amount', 'Income Amount', 'required|numeric');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('select_client', 'Client Name', 'required');

function get_product($crop_quantity,$per_rate)
{
    $q = $crop_quantity;
    $p = $per_rate;
    if(q!='' && p!='')
    {
        $total = $p * $q;
        $income_amount=$total;
    }
}
```

**view**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Crop Quantity</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="span6 m-wrap" value="<?echo $name->crop_quantity?>" name="crop_quantity" >
        <?php echo form_error('crop_quantity'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to display income_amount in form without submitting? (i,e as soon as user enters crop_quality and per_rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You done need to do anything with your controller. Add this change your view to

```
<script>
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('crop_quantity').value;    
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('per_rate').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('income_amount');  
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    result.value = myResult;


}
window.onload = calculate();
</script>


  <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Crop Quantity</label>
                        <div class="controls">
       <input type="text" id="crop_quantity" oninput="calculate()" class="span6 m-wrap" value="<?echo $name->crop_quantity?>" name="crop_quantity" >
                        <?php echo form_error('crop_quantity'); ?>        

                        </div>
                        </div>

                       <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Per Rate</label>
                        <div class="controls">
  <input type="text" id="per_rate" class="span6 m-wrap" value="<?echo $name->per_rate ?>" name="per_rate" oninput="calculate()">
                        <?php echo form_error('per_rate'); ?>        

                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Income Amount</label>
                        <div class="controls">
  <input type="text" id="income_amount" class="span6 m-wrap" value="<?echo $name->income_amount?>" name="income_amount" >
                        <?php echo form_error('income_amount'); ?>        

                        </div>
                        </div>
```

**Note:** I added attribute `id` in each input field. You can also add disabled field in output box.
**Note 2:** I have used `oninput="calculate()"` in the input fields too.
 **Example**

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('crop_quantity').value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('per_rate').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('income_amount'); 
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  result.value = myResult;
      
  
 }

window.onload = calculate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<table width="80%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>crop_quantity</th>
    <th>per_rate</th>
    <th>income_amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="crop_quantity" name="crop_quantity" type="text" oninput="calculate()" value="13" /></td>
    <td><input id="per_rate" name="per_rate" value="10" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="income_amount" name="income_amount" disabled/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit** Updates javascript

Comment: I have updated my post with example code that runs out of the box. You dont need to call it. Just Place it in your view (most likely at the begining of view)

Comment: Just place it in your view (most likely at the begining of view) in html, with script tag of course. (Which I forgot) adding it.

Comment: No, put it in your view, the script part. (I updated it)

Comment: Why You want to validate it? You said in your first comment that you only want it without submitting?

Comment: @Arthi also remove get_product() from your controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81151/discussion-between-arthi-and-uzumaki-ichigo).

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in to your Controller Post :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('crop_quantity', 'Crop Quantity', 'required|numeric');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('per_rate', 'Per Rate', 'required|numeric|callback_get_product');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('income_amount', 'Income Amount', 'required|numeric|callback_validate_amount');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('select_client', 'Client Name', 'required');
```

Add a New function with name 'validate_amount' in same controller  ( hint : callback_validate_amount)

```
function validate_amount() {
    $q = $this->input->post('crop_quantity');
    $p = $this->input->post('per_rate');
    $income_amount = $this->input->post('income_amount');

    $total = $p * $q;
    if ($income_amount == $total) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_amount', 'The %s field must contain the product of  crop_quantity and per_rate');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

uzumaki ichigo solutions looks working just want to add some point

1.please check `<?(shorthand tags) are enabled or not else use <?php instead of ?>`

2.One more thing is that there should be space between `<? and echo`